# AJAX request form in Internet Explorer - reCaptcha causes form fields to be reset on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, recaptcha

After a lot of debugging, and isolating issues, I realized that the reCaptcha I've placed in my request form is causing fields to be reset.

With AJAX, I'm sending form data to a PHP file for validation and email submission. When you submit the form with errors (lets say you forgot to fill something out), it scrolls you to the top of the page, where the $.post() function returns errors.

In all other browsers, this works perfectly. In Internet Explorer, *all* form fields are reset once the request has been submitted, and the errors have been returned.

```
 // jQuery used to submit form
 $("#support-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(".submit").attr("value", "Sending...");
      $.post('/process-support.php', $("#support-form").serialize(), function(data) {
       $('.results').html(data);
       Recaptcha.reload();
      });
    }
});
```

Then, when I removed the Captcha from the HTML, Internet Explorer started handling the errors and form fields properly.

Has anyone else came across a reCaptcha / Internet Explorer bug like this?

Comment: Why are you doing a `.reload()` on `Recaptcha` when you successfully submit the form?  This seems unnecessarily redundant as I believe `Recaptcha` automatically reloads itself after a code is used successfully.

Comment: Since the page doesn't reload, the captcha stays the same. After submission, it doesn't look like it changes automatically.

Comment: Hmm... yes, this may be the case.  I just looked at my Recaptcha form with jQuery Validate.  I just remove the entire form and replace with a "thank-you" message upon successful submission.  I am assuming most people don't need to see the form after they've already submitted it.  I only reload captcha when there is some kind of ajax submission failure.

Comment: Yeah--that's why I'm reloading it. I validate in the php file, so all the data is sent there, returns any errors, and the jQuery displays them. When the form is submitted, reCaptcha can't use the same code twice, so it needs to be reloaded if *any* errors in the form are returned.

This issue is only when any errors are returned, and in IE it resets all form fields. Pretty odd bug if you ask me...

Comment: I understand, but I don't see any conditional code.  Something like `if error { reload.captcha } else {"thank-you"}`.  Also, construct a demo so we can help you.  Otherwise, this is all guesswork.

Comment: Yeah, I just reloaded it on every submission instead of only when there's an error. I relocated the Recaptcha.reload() to my PHP file and it returns only when there's errors. Still the same problem in IE. Also, since this uses PHP and reCaptcha, It's not easy to build a quick demo unless I host it on my server.

Comment: I've never seen this problem.  Again, please construct some kind of demo.  Specify which versions of IE.

Comment: I've mainly tested on IE9. And I edited my last comment about making a demo.

Comment: I understand demos are not easy, but without one, you'll likely not get quality answers, just random guesses.  Unless you're lucky enough to find somebody that's had your exact problem.